# Reference for branching processes

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes

A popular model of a continuous time branching process was introduced around 1970, which is now called the Crump-Mode-Jagers branching process, was introduced here:

A General Age-Dependent Branching Process. I & II, by Kenny Crump and Charles J. Mode in 1969
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X6890005X 
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X69902108

In this process, one starts with a single individual at time $0$. This individual gives birth multiple times during its lifetime $L_x$ (which may be infinite), and the points of birth are given by some point process $\mathcal P$ on $\mathbb R_+$. Whenever a new individual is born, he initiates an independent copy of $\mathcal P$ and starts giving birth to more individuals until its lifetime ends. The lifetimes of each individual are i.i.d according to some distribution.

There are various results concerning the Malthusian growth rates of such processes and limiting distributions of the number of individuals at large times $t$. Some of these are contained in the following papers:

1. A Limit Theorem for a Class of Supercritical Branching Processes, by R. A. Doney, 1972
2. On the Convergence of Supercritical General (C-M-J) Branching Processes, Olle Nerman, 1981
3. The Growth and Composition of Branching Populations, by Peter Jagers and Olle Nerman, 1984
4. Asymptotic Properties of Super-Critical Branching Processes II: Crump-Mode and Jirina Processes, by N. H. Bingham and R. A. Doney, 1975
5. Mean-Square and Almost-Sure Convergence of Supercritical Age-Dependent Branching Processes, by Edgar Z. Ganuza and S. D. Durham , 1974

Since it is very hard to look at all the old papers to gather existing results (getting access to them being hard too), I was hoping that there is a book on branching processes which covers this topic in some detail, and states what is the current stage of results in this area. The standard book--- "Branching processes" by Athreya and Ney unfortunately does not cover this topic, because these developments were after the publication of the book.

Any pointers to references such as books or survey articles are welcome!

Comment: http://mypage.iu.edu/~rdlyons/prbtree/prbtree.html

Comment: Thanks for this reference. Although it does not consider the CMJ branching process, it is more up-to-date than Athreya & Ney.